# Find Max matrix & minimum Matrix out of given matrixes

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm new to c++ and opencv . I have 3 matrices, out of that three matrices i want to find the Max matrix and minimum Matrix, for an example

A=[ 1 2 3]  B= [ 2 4 6]  c=[4 8 12] then A is the minimum and C is the matrix that has got high scalar values , Are there any method to find it as it is , Any help is appreciated.

On the otherhad i tried as follows , But it is incorrect.

```
Mat A=imread("") // intialise the mat 1X3
Mat B=  //intialise the mat 1X3
if (A>B) printf("Matrix A greater than B") // this line encounter the Error that is not the correct way of doing that.
```

Comment: When exactly do you consider a matrix to be greater than another matrix?

Comment: @Nico Schertler i don't know the exact way of doing it , but i need to find small matrix

Comment: Maybe compare the average values?

Comment: But before that you should at least see the documentation for How to iterate through pixels of Opencv mat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi OpenCV has cv::min and max function implemented for you! Here is a sample usage! Hope this helps!

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Fill Random Numbers in 3 Mats
    Mat mTest(5,5,CV_8UC3),mMin,mMax;   
    randn(mTest,Scalar::all(125),Scalar::all(100));

    Mat mTest_3[3];
    split(mTest, mTest_3);

    //Find Min and max from 3 Mats!

    mMin=cv::min(mTest_3[0],cv::min(mTest_3[1],mTest_3[2]));
    mMax=cv::max(mTest_3[0],cv::max(mTest_3[1],mTest_3[2]));

    cout<< "Inputs 1: \n"<<mTest_3[0]<<"\n";
    cout<< "Inputs 2: \n"<<mTest_3[1]<<"\n";
    cout<< "Inputs 3: \n"<<mTest_3[2]<<"\n";

    cout<< "Min : \n"<<mMin<<"\n";
    cout<< "Max : \n"<<mMax<<"\n";

}
```